# How to stay comfort in airport for a long connecting flight

Tags: comfort, travel

I m travelling next week and the airport stay is 12 hours. I wanted to find out how can I make myself comfortable as I cannot leave airport because of visa.

What stuff should I carry for myself and kids because it is hot now a days.

Comment: You will probably get a better answer on Travel.SE.

Comment: @Chenmunka thanks

Comment: Part of every long journey is 'mindset'. I developed the ability to almost entirely switch off from my surroundings when travelling. [I've no clue how I did it, so I couldn't teach it to anyone else.] This was back before any form of portable entertainment, laptops, phones, pads etc, so there was a lot of time with 'nothing happening'.

Comment: Being in an airport by yourself for 12 hours is one thing, but having children with you in a confined area for that long is quite another.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few pay-per-use lounges run by airports or private/unaffiliated airline companies located within busy airports.  Certain airlines also will offer day passes to their private lounges. Access is typically open to any passenger, regardless of which airline or "class" they are flying in (First Class, Business Class, Economy, etc.).  It can cost up to $80 for a day pass, although some airlines offer hourly rates.  Well worth the money!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing which airport would help.

For instance, we used [*Jamaica Sangster Airport Lounge Access and Fast-Track Lines 2023 - Montego Bay*](https://www.viator.com/tours/Montego-Bay/Layover-Lounge-Access-Club-Mobay-at-Sangster-International-Airport/d432-6432MOBAY) while waiting for departure:

> Travel like a true VIP when you relax in the private lounge to wait for your flight, using the high-speed Wi-Fi and enjoying the beverages and snacks. This pass allows the stress-free Jamaican atmosphere to follow you to Sangster International Airport.
>
> - Separate arrival and departure lounges are available — choose one or both
> - Skip the crowded airport terminals for the relaxing atmosphere of a comfortable lounge
> - Enjoy cold and hot beverages, as well as tapas, sandwiches, fruit and other snacks
> - Take advantage of the included Wi-Fi, and catch up on the latest magazines and newspapers
> - Receive fast-track service through security, immigration and customs lines
>
> ---
>
> - Dedicated VIP Priority Lane
> - Phone calls to the USA, Canada and UK landlines
> - Snacks and beverages
> - Private restrooms
> - Complimentary WiFi
> - VIP lounge access

We certainly didn't regret it.
The difference between that and the general lounge was incredible.
And if you include the free food and drinks, it almost pays for itself.

(I know this sounds like I'm advertising, but I'm not.)

Not all airports have such facilities, and those that do are probably more expensive, but as I said, knowing which airport would help.
And as @Chenmunka said, [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) is a good place to ask about specific locations.